# Matlab: How to obtain 3d image from grayscale gradient

Tags: matlab, plot, gradient

I have a 2D microscopical image of a surface in grayscale. Now I want to plot this in 3d transforming the gradient from the image into height (by integration I thought). Trying 2d-integration of grdx&grdy didn't produce any useful results.

Which way would you suggest to do that? 
I'm not so familiar with the different ways of plotting and whether to use imgradient and somehow combine Gmag and Gdir or to use imgradientxy and combine Gx and Gy(is the magnitude here already in the matrix of Gx,y?).

Any help is appreciated - thank you very much!

Comment: Unclear if you just want to plot something pretty or get the actual surface heights across the image. For the latter, `imgradient` only works with the grayscale values in your image - and if these are genuinely related to the height I don't see what information is added by passing them through `imgradient` and then trying to convert them back again.

Comment: I have this image http://i.imgur.com/LnoL6wJ.png and want to make it 3dimensional since the gradient should refer to gradient of the 3d image (it's a surface with hemispheres on it)

Comment: Presuming that the illumination is such that "bright" here means flat (background, tops of the hemispheres) and "dark" = steep edges, what you have is already to some extent a gradient image.  The issue you will have is working out a way of getting the direction right - e.g. as I move from one side of the image to the other, does a strong gradient mean "height up" or "height down"? Possibly start with a circle finding method (Hough etc) and go from there.

Comment: Yes thats true. When I integrate the negative gradient I get some results but the hemispheres have a big crater because of the directional issue. I use hough anyway in the script anyway so I considered setting all gradients within circles to 0. I have the circle center and the circle radius, just thinking: What is th best way to get all gradient values in that circle, i.e. how to get a circular area inside a matrix.

Comment: I found some example code, the following produces steep zylindrical shapes. I think it's due to the nature of the image the only possibly or can somebody think of something? My only idea would be to ajust the mask to a hemispherial shape and thereby creating hemispheres. `imageSize=size(img);
for k=1:size(handles.cirrad)
    [xx,yy] = ndgrid((1:imageSize(1))-handles.circen(k,1),(1:imageSize(2))-handles.circen(k,2));
    mask = (xx.^2 + yy.^2)<handles.cirrad(k)^2;
    img(mask) = 0;
end
[x,y]=imgradientxy(img);
x=-1*x;
y=-1*y;

figure;
h=surf(intgrad2(x,y));
set(h, 'edgecolor','none')`

Answer (score 1):

What does this do for you?

a is the path to your image.

```
[b,c] = imgradient(a);
surf(b);
```

edit:

```
a1 = imread('LnoL6wJ.png');
a = a1(:,:,3); 
[b,c] = imgradient(a);
h = surf(b);
set(h, 'edgecolor','none')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It gives me a very dark plot many peaks which to not correspond to the surface: http://i.imgur.com/rHOftkz.png with this being the real image http://i.imgur.com/LnoL6wJ.png

Comment: Have a look at my edit, if you run that and then change the angle a bit it'll look like this http://i.imgur.com/8mR6ZL7.png It probably isn't perfect for you but is it along the right lines?

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes it's similar to what I now obtained, I guess it's the best possible result cause the gradient is near infinty and a true mapping of the hemispheric surface is not really possible with this data. I'll try to obtain different data I think.